# Effects of manually editing gmapping maps?

Tags: navigation, gmapping, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a map of my house generated by gmapping and now I am using it with amcl for navigation.  Does it make sense to clean up the map in an image editor?  For example, if you have a hallway wall that is slightly jagged in the original map, does it make sense to replace the original pixels with a perfectly straight line?  I'm just wondering if this would help or hinder amcl for subsequent navigation.

Thanks!

patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12217/effects-of-manually-editing-gmapping-maps?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cleaning up the map as you're suggesting shouldn't hurt localization performance, but probably won't help either.  By default, `amcl` uses a likelihood field model when interpreting laser data; this model has the effect of "blurring" the obstacles in the map, so moving a pixel a bit one way or the other won't have a huge effect.

If you compare performance with both maps, I'd be interested to know the results.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-12-05**:
Thanks Brian!  I'm about to run some amcl endurance tests with the TurtleBot.  If I get time to run them with different versions of the map, I'll post back the results.

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-08-30**:
Can i draw a complete map(.pgm file) on my own and feed that to Robot for navigation? if so how can this be accomplished?

**Comment by [pallavbakshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28889/pallavbakshi/) on 2017-02-02**:
@Kishore Kumar - Did you find a way? Even though that should be highly unlikely since the map was constructed without odometry and it will hard to make the map interactive on RVIZ.